# How can I convert Date picker data to Text String?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, datepicker

I am trying to teach myself HTML I am very new but am making headway however I have run into an issue. I want to use a date picker to fill a blank with a string of text.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="DayOW">Day of the week:</label>
  <input type="date" id="DayOW" name="DayOW">
  <div Id="DayOW">_______________</div>
</form>
```

Above is what I have, how can I fill the ___________ with MM/DD/YYY as text based on what is selected in the date picker?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use JavaScript to update the content of the  based on the value selected in the date picker. You'll need to add an event listener to the date input to detect changes and then update the content of the  accordingly.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="DayOW">Day of the week:</label>
  <input type="date" id="DayOW" name="DayOW" oninput="updateDate()">
  <div id="output">_______________</div>

  <script>
    function updateDate() {
      // Get the value of the date input
      var selectedDate = document.getElementById("DayOW").value;

      // Convert the selected date to the desired format (MM/DD/YYYY)
      var formattedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
      var mm = formattedDate.getMonth() + 1; // Months are zero-based
      var dd = formattedDate.getDate();
      var yyyy = formattedDate.getFullYear();

      // Update the content of the div with the formatted date
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
      outputDiv.textContent = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    }
  </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The date format that you request is the US way of representing the date. If you have a date the US format can be created using the [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) object.

When you are using a form a really handy way to update a text is by using the [`<output>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) element. It can have a name just like the form and the other form fields, so it is easy to refer to.

```js
document.forms.form01.dayow.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let date = new Date(e.target.value);
  let usdate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date);
  form.output.value = usdate;
});
```

```html
<form name="form01" action="/action_page.php">
  <label>Day of the week: <input type="date" name="dayow"></label>
  <div><output name="output"></output></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) just make sure you set everything to UTC timezone since the default date value has no time or time zone associated with it. BTW, *"day of the week"* usually refers to the weekday (ex. Thursday) so I added that in the example below.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference <form>
const main = document.forms.main;
// Reference <fieldset>, <input>, and <output>s
const fc = main.elements;

// Register #main to the "input" event
main.oninput = convert;

/**
 * Convert a given date into en-US format and weekday.
 * Display each conversion in an <output>
 */
function convert(event) {
  /**
   * <input type="date"> .value is a string of a date in 
   * date time string format (date form) - yyyy-mm-dd
   */
  let iso8601 = fc.date.value;
  // console.log(iso8601);
  /**
   * Next a Date Object is instantiated. Since there was no
   * time given, it defaults to 12am UTC.
   */
  let dateTime = new Date(iso8601);
  // console.log(dateTime);

  /**
   * Define an options Object for each use of
   * .toLocalDateString(Date, options) method
   */
  let usFormat = {
    month: "2-digit", // Padded zero, ex. 01
    day: "2-digit", // As previous key/value
    year: "numeric", // 4 digits, ex. 2023 
    timeZone: "UTC" // Default timezone of "dateTime"
  };
  let dayOfWeek = {
    weekday: "long", // Monday - Sunday
    timeZone: "UTC" // Default timezone of "dateTime"
  };

  // Convert yyyy-mm-dd to mm/dd/yyyy
  let mmddyyyy = dateTime.toLocaleDateString("en-US", usFormat);
  // Get the weekday 
  let weekday = dateTime.toLocaleDateString("en-US", dayOfWeek);

  // Display "mmddyyyy" and "weekday" in it's own <output>
  fc.enUS.value = mmddyyyy;
  fc.day.value = weekday;
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI"
}

legend {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

label {
  font-weight: 700;
}

input {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  font: inherit;
}

output {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.15rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<form id="main">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Schedule</legend>
    <label for="date">Enter Date: </label>
    <input id="date" name="data-date" type="date"><br>
    <label for="enUS">mm/dd/yyyy: </label>
    <output id="enUS"></output><br>
    <label for="day">Day of the Week:  </label>
    <output id="day"></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```